# Show Hide Spoiler shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

Iv been able to add a quick-tag button that adds `[spoiler][/spoiler]` to my wp comment section but now I need to hide / show the text inside.

I was provided with the following code to add into my themes function.php but it doesn't look like the code is being executed because the page output is still `test [spoiler]hint[/spoiler]` and not `test View Spoiler>>`

```
`// jQuery Spoiler Function`
function add_spoilers() {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("span.spoiler").hide();

         $(\'<a class="reveal">View Spoiler &raquo;</a> \').insertBefore(\'.spoiler\');

        $("a.reveal").click(function(){
            $(this).parents("p").children("span.spoiler").fadeIn(100);
            $(this).parents("p").children("a.reveal").fadeOut(100);
        });

    }); 
    </script>

    <style>
        /* If you want you can add custom CSS here for the spoilers!  Below is what I use on my blog. */
        a.reveal:hover { cursor:pointer; }
        span.spoiler { background-color:#FCE586; }
    </style>
';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_spoilers');

// Spoiler Shortcode
function spoiler_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$output = '<span class="spoiler">';
$output .= do_shortcode($content);
$output .= '</span>';

return $output;
}

add_shortcode('spoiler', 'spoiler_shortcode');`
```